# Dynamically scrolling through a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to program a listview with display instructions to scroll as voice instructions are played in the background. I currently have it set up in a timer so that it gives the voice instruction time to complete before scrolling to the next display instruction. However, it seems to only scroll once even though the loop is set to loop through the number of instructions available which correspond to the number of instructions on display in the list. Depending on the timer setting, it will scroll to the middle of the list or scroll straight to the bottom just once without stopping at each list item in the loop position.
I would appreciate any ideas as to how I can achieve this in android development. Thanks

Code:

```
 public void displayInstructions(ArrayList<Voice_Instructions>instructions,ListView DisplayInstructionListView)
{
    if(instructions!= null) 
     {
        final ListView list=DisplayInstructionListView;
        DisplayInstructionAdapter displayinstructionAdapter = new DisplayInstructionAdapter(this,instructions);
        list.setAdapter(displayinstructionAdapter);

        for (int i=0; i<instructions.size();i++)
        {
            final int  t=i;
            new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) 
            {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish()
                {
                  list.smoothScrollToPosition(t);
                }
              }
            }.start();
        }

    }
     else
         {
           Log.e("no intrctns db", " null");
         }
```

}

Comment: You're scheduling all the countdown timers at the same time, ie. quickly going through the for loop and probably spinning up a new thread for each timer that will all end around the same point in time instead of waiting for the last one to finish

Comment: How do I stagger the timers to take care of that?